# How to send zoom command to ip camera with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera

Trying to control an IP camera with Flutter using the easy_onvif library, but I can't get the camera to zoom. I've tried using the zoomIn function provided by the library, but without success. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get the camera to perform zoom commands? Here is the code I am using to communicate with the camera:

```
setZoom() async {
    final onvif = await Onvif.connect(
        host: "192.168.1.18:8999", username: "", password: "");

    var profiles = await onvif.media.getProfiles();
    var profileToken = await profiles.first.token;

    var ptzCommand = await onvif.ptz;
    print("zoom+");
    await ptzCommand.zoomIn(profileToken);
    print("zoom++");
}
```

--SOS: Many flutter libraries, which connect to send commands or stream are deprecated, and this makes it difficult to find an answer to my problems with flutter, mainly for being a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The ONVIF connect and token command can take a long time. And, the zoom is really negligible. The Zoom command needs to be placed inside a long press callback.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Connect the camera first. Use logs/print statements to confirm it worked without any issue
2. Get the token. This occasionally takes a long time to complete, so add a log to confirm)
3. Then call the zoom command

P.S. - Depending on the latency you can see the screen zoom with a significant delay.

Here is the code:

```
class OnVIFService {
  OnVIFService();

  Onvif onvif;
  String token;

  Future<void> connect({@required String ip}) async {
    onvif = await Onvif.connect(
      host: ip,
      username: 'admin', // replace with your username
      password: '123456', // replace with your password
    );

    log('OnVIFService: connected to $ip');
  }

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    final profiles = await onvif.media.getProfiles();
    final profile = profiles.first;
    token = profile.token;

    log('OnVIFService: got token $token');
  }

  Future<void> moveLeft() async {
    await onvif.ptz.moveLeft(token);
  }

  Future<void> moveRight() async {
    await onvif.ptz.moveRight(token);
  }

  Future<void> moveUp() async {
    await onvif.ptz.moveUp(token);
  }

  Future<void> moveDown() async {
    await onvif.ptz.moveDown(token);
  }

  Future<void> stop() async {
    await onvif.ptz.stop(token);
  }

  Future<void> zoomIn() async {
    await onvif.ptz.zoomIn(token);
  }

  Future<void> zoomOut() async {
    await onvif.ptz.zoomOut(token);
  }
}
```